# The multi-part identifier "inserted.id_ahs" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatehargaahs
ON tbl_hitash
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE tbl_ahs
    SET harga = (SELECT SUM(harga_satuan)
                 FROM tbl_hitash
                 WHERE tbl_ahs.id_ahs = tbl_hitash.id_ahs)
    WHERE id_ahs = inserted.id_ahs
```

I tried to use this query but got the error

> The multi-part identifier "inserted.id_ahs" could not be bound.

Comment: You're not using the `Inserted` pseudo table anywhere in your `UPDATE` statement ....

Comment: Why do you delete your question after getting an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/41453822/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually **use** the `Inserted` pseudo table inside your `UPDATE` statement in order to reference a column from it!

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatehargaahs
ON tbl_hitash
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE a
    SET harga = (SELECT SUM(h.harga_satuan)
                 FROM tbl_hitash h
                 WHERE a.id_ahs = h.id_ahs)
    FROM tbl_ahs a
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON a.id_ahs = i.id_ahs
```