# Get Error SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I run the following query

```
CREATE TRIGGER ubahjumlahupah ON tbl_pkrjbhn
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE tbl_hitash SET
jumlah_upah = (SELECT (tbl_pkrjbhn.harga_satuan*tbl_hitash.upah_hitash)
               FROM tbl_hitash, tbl_pkrjbhn 
               WHERE tbl_hitash.id_pkrjbhn = tbl_pkrjbhn.id_pkrjbhn)
FROM tbl_hitash
```

but i get error :(

Comment: Thanks for the report on the current status of your project. Was there a *question*?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear: your `SELECT` result returns more than one value, so the query results in:

```
CREATE ...
 ...    
UPDATE ... SET
jumlah_upah = (more than one value)
```

So you need to make sure the  `SELECT` command returns a single value so that it can be assigned to the `jumlah_upah` variable.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure it is possible to know _how_ to achieve a single record based on the information in the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed, so I was focusing in the _why_ this error is happening.

Comment: We might also note that without a WHERE clause on the UPDATE statement, *every* row in the table will be updated. With that aside, how does this answer the question OP asked? Was there a question?